# Possible to use another application as default camera application?

Tags: rooting, camera

Many apps let u use only the default built-in camera app. They not allow you to choose a third party app, such as the app "fake camera". Is there a way to remove/replace the default camera app? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. At least, on some devices. But without knowing anything about your device, it's hard to answer your question.

For example, on Android 8, you have a menu like this:[image] If you have a search option in your settings, then you can easily search for "default", and you will find it easily.

Comment: Changing default camera is unfortunately disabled on Android 11 and newer, see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232306/64465)