# How Do We Set the Default Camera App in Android 11?

Tags: camera, default-applications, developer-preview, android-11

In Android 11 Beta 3, Google is blocking the ability for third-party camera apps to handle photo/video requests on behalf of other apps. Interested developers can read [the release notes](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes-11#media-capture) for the rationale behind this change.

However, there is one odd sentence in that explanation:

> A user can set a third party camera app as the default camera app.

Here is the "Default apps" screen in Settings:

[image: Default Apps Settings Screen in Android 11]

I don't see "Camera" on there. And if I search for "default" in Settings, I do not see an option for setting the default camera app.

So... how do we set the default camera app in Android 11?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am on Android 11 (Pixel 4a) and was searching to do this and I recalled this question (had posted an answer and deleted, not being correct) . Here's the answer from [Android 11 Changelog — Full List of All 50+ New Features](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/android-11-changelog-full-list-all-50-new-features-0258964/)

> **You Can't Change the Default Camera**
> To prevent malicious apps from capturing your location, Google has removed the ability to set a third-party camera app as default. You can continue to use the third-party app as usual, but if an app requests to use the camera app, it will use the preinstalled one. But the change isn't as dramatic as it sounds — you can still use the cameras that are built into apps such as Snapchat and set shortcuts to third-party apps.

As Andrew said in comments(now deleted)
, the release notes do not include that sentence to the effect that third party apps can be set as default camera app.